# toggle between two or more ul lists that if one is click others lists automatically return in initial state like never clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If i click first ul list it slideToggle() of its li and also if i click second ul list it slideToggle() of its li but, the first ul list is shown also. I want if click first ul list the second ul list li must be disappear automatically and so with clicking second ul the first ul li must be disappear. my code is

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("#block1").click(function(){
   $("#none1, #none2, #none3").slideToggle();
  } );
  $("#block2").click(function(){
   $("#none4, #none5, #none6").slideToggle();
  } );
 });
```

```css
#none1, #none2, #none3, #none4, #none5, #none6{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="first">
  <li id="block1"><a href="#">Block1</a></li>
  <li id="none1">None1</li>
  <li id="none2">None1</li>
  <li id="none3">None1</li>
</ul>

<ul id="second">
  <li id="block2"><a href="#">Block2</a></li>
  <li id="none4">None2</li>
  <li id="none5">None2</li>
  <li id="none6">None2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified version that should do what you need using [`siblings()`](https://jsfiddle.net/bhc8w9bL/) and [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to target the other *"block"* elements

```
$(function(){
    var $blocks = $('#block1, #block2').click(function(){
        // slide up all siblings of other block(s)
        $blocks.not(this).siblings().slideUp();
        // toggle slide this one
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bhc8w9bL/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your event handler you are only telling the code to show certain elements, never to hide other ones.

You can solve this by doing this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#block1").click(function(){
        $("#none1, #none2, #none3").slideToggle();
        if($('#none4').is(':visible')) { // block 2 lis are visible
          $("#none4, #none5, #none6").slideToggle();
        }
    });
    $("#block2").click(function(){
        $("#none4, #none5, #none6").slideToggle();
        if($('#none1').is(':visible')) { // block 1 lis are visible
          $("#none1, #none2, #none3").slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/ZWQvRv?editors=1111)

Comment: Thanx for answering sir , its complicated the above is simple.